# Vertical-Alignment of Image in Navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a website that I am developing utilizing the Bootstrap 4 framework. I am trying to create a `navbar` with the `navbar-brand` in the center. I was able to place the `navbar-brand` in the center with a `navbar-nav` on each side of the `navbar-brand`. Please find below the code that I utilized. My issue is that the `navbar-brand` is vertically aligned in the center of the `navbar`.
How can I align the `navbar-brand` to the bottom of the `navbar` and have the excess stick out at the top of the `navbar` without adjusting the margins?

```css
#hdrContainer {
  background-color: #0a3782;
}

.container {
  background-color: inherit;
}

#tblHeader {
  width: 100%;
  /*font-size: .8125rem;*/
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: right;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#tblHeader tr {
  height: 50px;
}

.breadcrumb {
  background-color: inherit;
  margin-bottom: initial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.breadcrumb .active {
  color: inherit;
}

#socialbrand {
  text-align: right;
}

#mainNavbar {
  background-color: gray;
}

#mainNavbar .container .navbar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  max-height: 40px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-right: initial;
}

.form-control {
  width: 200px;
}

.btn-outline-navy {
  color: #f6b40e;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: #f6b40e;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="hdrContainer" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <table id="tblHeader">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" role="navigation">
              <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Commander, Naval Surface Force, US Pacific</li>
              </ol>
            </nav>
          </td>
          <td id="socialbrand" style="display: block; padding: .75rem 1rem;">Follow Us |
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-flickr" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-wordpress" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-youtube-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
              <form class="form-inline">
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm ml-auto mr-sm-2 float-right" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" type="search">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-navy my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
            </nav>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="mainNavbar" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Just an image -->
        <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto ml-auto" href="#">
          <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="75" height="75">
        </a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your question is not that clear, so make it more clear

Comment: @RohitGautam: I have tried to re-word the question to best get my issue across.

Comment: What is your purpose to do this, you can set navbar brand by using margins, why you don't wanna usee margins, any reason?

Comment: You shouldn't really use HTML tables for that. There's more modern ways to do a navbar in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution below makes use of the various flexbox utility classes available in Bootstrap, described in detail in the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content).
The `.navbar-brand` got wrapped into `<div id="logo">` in order to set it's `positioning` to `absolute`, and it's `bottom` position to `0`. That pushes down the logo container to the bottom of the navbar.
Additionally, I've added the `.d-none .d-lg-block` classes in order to hide the logo when the menu is collapsed.

Available as a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dferenc/pen/XzymGQ) as well.

```css
    /* Pushing logo to bottom */
    #logo {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    /* Basic styling to resemble to source */
    .navbar {
        background-color: gray;
    }

    #header {
        height: 100px;
        color: white;
        background-color: #0a3782;
        
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<div id="header">[header placeholder]</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-around" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </div>

            <div id="logo" class="d-none d-lg-block">
                <a class="navbar-brand m-0" href="#">
                    <img src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="75" height="75" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Item 4</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked Perfectly. Would you be able to help me on another issues I am trying to work out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540156/nav-pill-positioning